# accepts_nested_attributes_for does not update nested table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 tables cardapios and produtos, and when I want to update cardapios accepts_nested_attributes_for does not update produtos and _destroy = "1" does not delete produto. Follow bellow my code:

```
class Cardapio < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :imagem, CardapioImagemUploader

  belongs_to :empresa
  has_many :itens
  has_many :cardapios_produtos
  has_many :cardapios_eventos
  has_and_belongs_to_many :eventos
  has_and_belongs_to_many :produtos

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cardapios_produtos, reject_if: proc { |a| a[:produto_id].blank? or a[:preco].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
```

---

```
  def update
    authorize @cardapio
    atualiza_imagem

    binding.pry
    if @cardapio.update_attributes(cardapio_params)
      if params[:parent_controller].present?
        redirect_to controller: params[:parent_controller], action: params[:parent_action], id: params[:parent_id].to_i, notice: 'Cardapio was successfully updated.'
      else
        redirect_to cardapios_path, notice: 'Cardapio was successfully updated.'
      end
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

---

```
def cardapio_params
  params.require(:cardapio)
        .permit(
          :nome, :empresa_id, 
          :imagem, :imagem_crop_x, :imagem_crop_y, :imagem_crop_w, :imagem_crop_h, 
          evento_ids: [],
          cardapios_produtos_attributes: [
            :id, :cardapio_id, :produto_id, :preco, :destaque, :_destroy
          ]
        )
end
```

---

Bellow we have the result of binding.pry before update_attributes:

```
[1] pry(#<CardapiosController>)> cardapio_params
=> {"nome"=>"Cardapio BDD Light",
 "empresa_id"=>"3",
 "imagem_crop_x"=>"",
 "imagem_crop_y"=>"",
 "imagem_crop_w"=>"",
 "imagem_crop_h"=>"",
 "evento_ids"=>["", "1"],
 "cardapios_produtos_attributes"=>
  {"0"=>{"id"=>"4", "produto_id"=>"1", "preco"=>"5", "destaque"=>"0", "_destroy"=>"0"},
   "1"=>{"id"=>"5", "produto_id"=>"7", "preco"=>"20", "destaque"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"0"},
   "2"=>{"id"=>"22", "produto_id"=>"12", "preco"=>"13.5", "destaque"=>"0", "_destroy"=>"1"},
   "3"=>{"produto_id"=>"", "preco"=>"", "destaque"=>"0", "_destroy"=>"0"},
   "4"=>{"produto_id"=>"", "preco"=>"", "destaque"=>"0", "_destroy"=>"0"},
   "5"=>{"produto_id"=>"", "preco"=>"", "destaque"=>"0", "_destroy"=>"0"},
   "6"=>{"produto_id"=>"", "preco"=>"", "destaque"=>"0", "_destroy"=>"0"},
   "7"=>{"produto_id"=>"", "preco"=>"", "destaque"=>"0", "_destroy"=>"0"}}}
```

---

May anybody help me?

Comment: Your `has_and_belongs_to_many ` should actually be a `has_many through` relationship, since you have the `cardapios_produtos` join table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in this part `has_and_belongs_to_many :produtos` in model.  According to this documentation http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html
There is on one-to-one and one-to-many.
You should use `has_many`, or `has_one`.